# Missing data-reactroot attirbute in React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm on the process of upgrading some apps to React 16 and noticed that the attribute `data-reactroot` is gone from the generated root element.

While not super important, seems like we had some code and styles depending on that attribute. I tried to find any place where this change was documented, but couldn't. Is this change normal?

Before v16:

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="css-1vi9s5j" data-reactroot="">
    ...
```

After upgrade:

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="css-1vi9s5j">
    ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is intentional. We had some code in React that depended on it but we've since removed it.

I don't recommend to make your app's styling depend on such arguably internal attributes. Use your own CSS classes or data attributes for styling instead.

Comment: I agree, this was old code that I found "broke" after the upgrade. But as you say, it's arguably internal as it was right there in the DOM. No big deal, but wanted some confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

From the [React v15.0 changelog](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/master/content/blog/2016-04-07-react-v15.md):

> We are now using `document.createElement` instead of setting `innerHTML` when mounting components. This allows us to get rid of the `data-reactid` attribute on every node and make the DOM lighter. Using `document.createElement` is also faster in modern browsers and fixes a number of edge cases related to SVG elements and running multiple copies of React on the same page.

Comment: Notice I'm talking about `data-reactroot` not `data-reactid` and I'm upgrading to React 16, not React 15.